# Player being covered by glClearColor?

Tags: opengl, java

Here is a video of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vnDOB1Vk4o (this is the game I've been making for fun/practice).

You notice, in the beginning of the video, I walk off the map and into the black. When I do so the black covers the player.

I draw the player last in my code:

```
 // Draw the player & the world
public void draw(Graphics g, Graphics graphics, GameStateManager gsm) {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(player.getPlayerX() + " - " + player.getPlayerY());
    glViewport(-(int)player.getPlayerX() + 350, -(int)player.getPlayerY() + 300, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());  
    worldGen.worldGenerator();
    // Draw the player to the screen (60, 60)
    player.draw();

}
```

Comment: Make the viewport big again, and draw the player always in the same spot relative to the window.

Alternatively, don't move the viewport at all, and move the world image instead.

You're on target!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you moving the viewport? You should only really touch it when the screen resizes.

because you move the viewport everything outside it will not be drawn.

instead adjust the view matrix to move the "camera" to where the player is this allows you to have larger levels as well.